# API without a callback is not supported

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

My geolocation was working for a while, suddenly it no longer works.
Here is my code in the head:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

The script with my API:

```
axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',{
            params:{
            address: location,
            key: MyKey
          }
      })
```

I tried following the steps on the error but no change

Comment: What are `steps on the error`?

Comment: @mykaf Hirok has solved it in the comments.